# How do I compare a list of annual means with a baseline mean in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a task to compare a list of annual mean temperatures for a region with the mean temperature for a 20 year baseline period. I have calculated the means in an object (testmean) with [years] and [mean], and calculated the annual mean in a separate object (baseline). Thought it would be a simple loop getting R to run a t test against each row, to compare the significance of the difference from the baseline but it keeps telling me "not enough (x) observations"... help! please. What am I doing wrong?

```
years <- 1980:2020
anomalies <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(years)){
anomalies[i] <- t.test(testmean$mean[testmean$years==years[i]], mu=baseline)
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(testmean)` in order to make the issue reproducible.